# Fast Gaussian cdf function

Tags: java, gaussian

I would like to know the cheapest, dirtiest approximation of the Gaussian cdf.  Would it be a Taylor series or this method: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/21function/ErrorFunction.java.html

Comment: Have you considered a lookup table?

Comment: What does cheapest, dirtiest mean?  All cdf are btwn 0 and 1, so my cdf estimator function is F(x)~0.5 for all x.  Is that cheap and dirty enuf?

Comment: Voted down because there's no effort, from a long time, by the questioner in cooperating to come up with an answer. Basically this question seems to be abandoned.